# Wanted to eliminate the repetition in the classes created to reduce duplication

Tags: python, database, django, serialization, rest

Can some one help me on how to eliminate repetition to reduce duplication score on the below classes created in the code

```
class EnquiryFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = '__all__'


class EnquirySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # making sure if broker is not fetched then replace null value with
    # some resonable data as it will help in duing filter
        if len(validated_data.get('email_broker', instance.email_broker)) == 0:
            instance.email_broker = not_avbl

        instance.save()
        return instance


class EnquiryBrokerNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['broker_email_id']


class EnquiryAssignedUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['email_assigned_user']


class EnquiryInsuredNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['ef_insured_name']


class EnquiryObligorNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['ef_obligor_name']


class EnquiryCountryNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['el_country_name']


class EnquiryLimitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['enquirylog_limit']


class EnquiryDecisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = enquirylog
        fields = ['ef_underwriter_decision']


class NotesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = notes
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

`type` is just another type. Classes can be created in, and returned from, functions just fine. An approach kind of like

```
def basic_model_serializer(model, fields):
    _model, _fields = model, fields

    class _internal(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = _model
            fields = _fields

    return _internal

EnquiryFilterSerializer = basic_model_serializer(enquirylog, '__all__')
EnquiryBrokerNameSerializer = basic_model_serializer(enquirylog, ['broker_email_id'])
...
NotesSerializer = basic_model_serializer(notes, '__all__')

class EnquirySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... # unchanged due to update()
```

would let you abstract over the few differences of the most similar classes in a pretty natural way. Is it an improvement over your existing code? Maybe in some ways, maybe not in others.

Comment: I am getting error saying Unresolved reference to 'model' and Unresolved reference to 'fields'

Comment: @Sherlock Right, sorry about that, I got it too but forgot to put my workaround in the answer

Comment: Thank you I resolved the errors